# Did physicists solve the grandfather paradox?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, time-travel

Now, physicists are trying to send information backward in time. But, why are physicists almost sure that this would happen and why are they so confident about it? Did physicists solve the [grandfather paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_paradox)?

In that case it would mean that result would occur before the cause. That is very weird. Of course the universe is very weird(and hence very interesting) but is that the case? Can information be sent backward in time?

Comment: My preferred solution to the grandfather paradox would be to ban time travel, but that's (luckily) not the only possible answer.

Comment: Can you back up your claim that "physicists are trying to send information backward in time"?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22717/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2166/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @JanDvorak Sir,but I saw in one of the documentaries of BBC or discovery I don't correctly remember in which a physicist it trying to send information backward in time. That's why I wrote it here.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Causality only runs forward in the physical universe, to current knowledge.